# Error while setting up a Kafka connection in Apache Airflow - "config['bootstrap.servers'] must be provided"

Tags: python, apache-kafka, airflow, apache-kafka-connect

I encountered an error while trying to set up a connection to Apache Kafka in Apache Airflow. The specific error message I received is "config['bootstrap.servers'] must be provided." Despite having provided the Kafka server details, the issue persists.
Steps taken so far:
Installed the Kafka provider for Apache Airflow using the following pip command:
pip install apache-airflow-providers-apache-kafka
Accessed the Airflow UI and attempted to create the connection, but encountered the error mentioned above.
I have verified the configuration settings in the Airflow UI and ensured that the 'bootstrap.servers' parameter, which specifies the list of Kafka broker addresses, is included. However, the problem remains unresolved.
Would appreciate any insights or suggestions to troubleshoot this issue. Thank you in advance for your help.
[error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tADey.png)

Comment: I'm guessing that the JSON in the "Config Dict" field is invalid. Try putting 4 spaces before the `"bootstrap.servers"` key.

Comment: tried, doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have installed 'confluent-kafka' Python package. Installing this package resolved the issue for me.

Hope this helps.